# javascript | transitionend not firing

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am currently trying to make my own Javascript notice system using Javascript and CSS3 and utilising it's animations.

I want to detect when the element transition has finished so I can remove the element from the DOM.

The animation is called `animate-out` which is a custom one I made within CSS3 using only 2 keyframes.

I have a close button on the notice, which when I click it adds a class of `is-closed`. Once is-closed animation has finished I want to be able to detect this, which I am currently trying to find out via using a `console.log('finished');` however it seems as though the event is not being fired at all.

Here is my current code:

```
const close = document.querySelector('.close');
const notice = document.querySelector('.notice')

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
   notice.classList.add('is-closed');
});

notice.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    console.log('finished');
});

notice.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: transitionend is not firing, because you are not using transitions ...

Comment: I read on another Stack Overflow question that this is used to detect when a animation has finished too? Is that not correct?

Comment: Is it that hard to put two and two together, and type "animationend" into Google and see what happens ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using keyframes then you are using animation and not transitions.

The relevant event is [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)

Also read [Using animation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events)

Comment: I feel really stupid now! Thanks for pointing out that mistake!